# How to apply data summary only on the specified column in devexpress MVC gidview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, summary, devexpress-mvc

I am displaying the result using devexpress MVC Gridview, and I am using data summary.
By default, data summary is applied to all grouped columns.
I want this data summary to be displayed only when I group one particular column and it should be hidden for the rest of the columns.

say I have four columns,
"ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD".

Data summary should be available only to the "ColumnA"
And when I group ColumnB, C or D, there should be no data summary displayed for these columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,Inherited= true,AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SummaryColumnAttribute : Attribute
{          
    public SummaryColumnAttribute(SummaryItemType summaryItemType,bool showGroupsummary,bool showTotalSummary)
    {
        this.SummaryItemType = summaryItemType;
        this.ShowGroupSummary = showGroupsummary;
        this.ShowTotalSummary = showTotalSummary;
    }
}
```

and in model class apply this

```
[SummaryColumnAttribute(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum, true, true)]
public decimal OpeningBalance { get; set; }
```